# Android Soft Keyboard appears on EditText Longpress

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I've hide my Android default Soft Keyboard by setting (InputType.TYPE_NULL) and setting

```
<android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan" >
```

in Manifest file. It works fine onToch, onClick, onFocus but when I longClick the EditText and as soon as I release it, Soft Keyboard appears. What's the reason its appearing on LongClick? Any solution of it?

Comment: Might this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435662/how-to-disable-edittext-pop-up-when-edittext-is-longclicked

Comment: I override onLongClick listener on my Edittext and write code to hide Soft Keyboard and return true.. But this didn't work :(

Comment: Have a look at it almost similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657092/how-to-prevent-virtual-keyboard-displaying-when-long-press-on-edittext-widget, the one who ask the question, solve the problem by himself